# How to use drupal Color Box

Tags: drupal

Site on Drupal 6.
The site of about 3,000 photos and display them nicely to.
how to connect the module **ColorBox**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get content type of content with photos.
2. Change this content type display option.

OR

2: Create view and select color box preset as display.

Answer (score 0):

Why, consult the [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/colorbox.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/README.txt) of the module, of course!